# Create image from view/screen in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

Is it possible to create a bitmap image from a view or the screen in Android?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it. A simple one is to do the following:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(theView.getWidth(), theView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
theView.draw(c);
```